# Cloudflare firewall rule blocks bot traffic only partially

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

We’ve got some trouble with bot traffic (likely scraping) on a website that’s hosted on a fairly small server. The bot requests

- a large set of changing pages
- in irregular intervals
- in the order of ~1x/h
- from various IPs
- around the clock
- all at once - i. e. some 200 base pages in 5s
- no assets.

So it’s definitely bot traffic. Caching has proven useless because the set of hosted pages changes quite a bit, it fetches some very obscure subpages and never more than once or twice in several days. Thus, we attempted to use Cloudflare to soft-block the bot.

Currently, it always makes requests with this user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

That’s useful because our Linux userbase is otherwise very small. So I first created a firewall rule specifying `equals` this exact user agent and to present it with a captcha. That caught some 100 requests in 24h while some 5000 still got through. Thus I changed the filter to just `contains`

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
```

which catches ~1k per day while ~4k still get through.

What’s happening here? Neither the fact that these filters produce different results nor that only a subset of requests are caught makes sense to me unless this is a fairly sophisticated bot which is unlikely for such a small site.

It’s all the exact same user agent (as far as it’s visible to me / nginx / awk). All the requests do have Cloudflare IPs in the `X-Forwarded-For` shown in the access logs, I evaluated that with a bash script - they’re not circumventing CF somehow. (There are some for which `whois` doesn’t return `OrgName: Cloudflare` but I see legitimate requests coming from the same IPs. That very likely means that the `whois` data isn’t completely accurate. Plus that’s a small share overall.)

Before I start speculating how they could be working around the captcha - does someone have a simple explanation and solution for the problem?

Comment: 5000 requests in 24 hours hardly seems excessive.  Even peaking at 200 requests in five minutes in barely more than one request a second. This doesn't seem to be worth worrying about, even for a small server.

Comment: That's 200 requests in 5 seconds, not 5 minutes. (At least as per log messages, I'm not sure when _exactly_ they arrive - nginx only logs the request after the backend has responded so it's likely they're even closer together.) The issue is that this creates huge spikes in memory usage on the backend and short outages until requests are processed. Yes, that means that PHP-FPM is not configured well, but unfortunately the server hosts several sites in Docker and accounting for such spikes is nontrivial with several FPM daemons. Easier to just block the aberrant behavior on the incoming side.